# SSL curl doesn't work c++

Tags: c++, ssl, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to download a page that use ssl. I've to login on that page but I have empty page caused by a srange error.

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, "a.crt");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "a.crt");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.org");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT); 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl); 


    if(res != CURLE_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));        
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
cout << res;
```

What I have as output is:

```
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* Connected to example.org (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: a.crt
  CApath: a.crt
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to example.org:443
* Closing connection 0
curl_easy_perform() failed: SSL connect error
35
```

I can't understand why
Thank's

Comment: There might be a lot of reasons for this. These kind of errors are hard to debug and the more details you add to your question the better. Check if it works with a browser, check against [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html), try to follow the tips in my [SSL debugging howto](http://noxxi.de/howto/ssl-debugging.html). If you don't understand this or still need help publish at least the URL you have problems with and the version of curl you use and with which compile time options, i.e. especially which TLS library is used by curl.

Comment: Can I have an example of curl whit ssl? So I try to use it on that site.
I've looked on the web but there is not an easy example.